# Heroku: Fatal error at Commit

Tags: git, heroku

I have logged in heroku by terminal and wrote:git commit -m "intial commit".
I'm getting the following error:who are you "could not find your email addres"
How can I solve this?
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like git is not configured yet. The heroku toolbelt has installed git for you, so you can start with the "Set up git" section of [this github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#set-up-git).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your username and email for commit attribution:

```
git config --local user.name "My Name"
git config --local user.email myemail@example.com
```

If you want to configure this for all repositories on that machine, just remove the `--local` flag.

These tokens are tied to commits, so that people can find who did that particular change. You can make them up; however, providing a correct email address and name allows your fellow colleagues to track the changes back to you. Moreover, services like GitHub use email address to link commits to GH users.